# How to run matlab m-file script on a linux server

Tags: matlab

I am new with using servers and currently, my PC has *Windows 10* and *Matlab 2016b*. I have very long *Matlab* codes saved as *m-files* and when running these *m-files* on my PC, it takes a long time.

However, I can access our Linux server using *Putty* with a given ID and password. So, how I can run my *Matlab* codes on our server instead of on my local PC?

Comment: I assume that Linux server has Matlab installed on it as well?

Comment: No, I did not installed Matlab on Linux server,
Should I install it? Please, how I can install it and then how I can run matlab m-file code on the server. I am new on dealing with the server.

Comment: you can install it on the linux server, only if you have the linux version of the Matlab setup. AND also if you have the rights/permissions to install things on the linux server.

Comment: Oh, I have only Matlab 2016b version that I working on it using windows 10. So, can I install it on the Linux server?

Comment: Could you share some useful links about how I can install Matlab on remote Linux server?

Comment: I don't think, you can use the same matlab setup for windows and linux.

Comment: here is a [link](https://xunyunliu.github.io/post/install_matlab/) on how to install matlab on linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185786/discussion-between-mohsen-ali-and-joey-mallone).

Comment: Ask the server administrator to install MATLAB on it. Unless are the administrator, you shouldn’t even try to install MATLAB there. If you are the administrator, you should know how to do all these things already. If you are the administrator and don’t know how to do all of this, search for answers or ask your own on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com),  not here, as Stack Overflow is for questions related to programming.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Linux server has *Matlab* installed on it as well, (and that it has also been added to the *path* on the server), you can run your *Matlab* scripts from the terminal, simply by entering in the terminal, `$ matlab your_script_name.m`.

Also, there is the option to start *Matlab* on the remote server in command-line mode, by typing at the prompt `$ matlab -nodesktop`.

Finally, if you want to know a way on how to get your m-files from your PC to the remote Linux server, you can use a tool like *winscp*, which is often present in the company of *putty*.